# How can I get my Huawei Dongle E3531 to work on Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite) please

Tags: macos, usb-modem

I have just now updated my Mac to Yosemite OS X 10.10 and my Huawei Modem E3531 does not work at all, no problems on Maverick OS X 10.9

Comment: Check whether your provider has new drivers. This happened at Lion/Mountain Lion release too

Answer (score 1):

Go to your network settings and "add new hardware " if you have already installed the driver for the dongle as mentioned in the answer above, you will find your device listed there.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout a newer driver here -> http://www74.zippyshare.com/v/54915703/file.html

This was originally posted here -> https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6605462

Comment: I've downloaded the zipfile and installed it but nothing happend how to fix it please ?

Answer (score 0):

This advice helped me:

> just double click on the mbbservice executable and run it :
>
> `/Library/StartupItems/MobileBrServ/mbbservice`

https://discussions.apple.com/message/26872899#26872899

Found via [Andrew's answer](https://superuser.com/a/840430/37154).